# Can i prevent notepad++ deleting empty spaces between closing and opening XML tags when going from Linarize to Pretty Print to Linarize

Tags: xml, notepad++

i have some an XML file where some closing and opening tags contain spaces in between them which i want to remain as spaces.

```
<test_id="123">content</test> <test_id="456">content</test>
```

In Notepad++ when i change to pretty print using ctrl+shift+alt+b then back to linarize XML using ctrl+shift+alt+l the empty spaces are being automatically removed.

```
<test_id="123">content</test><test_id="456">content</test>
```

Does anyone know a way of preventing this from happening? Thanks

Notepad++ v6.5.5 Using XML tools plugin v2.4.8

Comment: Which version of Notepad++? What command (and plugin) are you using? Provide a short example of the original, the pretty printed and the final files. Please [edit] the question to provide the missing details.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the text that is changed. Putting it in the main question allows things to be formatted neatly. Writing it in an comment makes it hard to read.